# ceil() php неправильно считает?

Tags: php

```
$abc = ceil((123+3.5)/1.15);
echo $abc
```

выходит 111, а должно быть 110 :(
ведь результат сложения 110, и округление целого числа до целого должно быть так же 110?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Числа с плавающей точкой](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.float.php#language.types.float)

> Кроме того, рациональные числа, которые могут быть точно представлены в виде чисел с плавающей точкой с основанием 10, например, 0.1 или 0.7, не имеют точного внутреннего представления в качестве чисел с плавающей точкой с основанием 2, вне зависимости от размера мантиссы. Поэтому они и не могут быть преобразованы в их внутреннюю двоичную форму без небольшой потери точности. Это может привести к **неожиданным результатам**: например, `floor((0.1+0.7)*10)` скорее всего вернет `7` вместо ожидаемого `8`, так как результат внутреннего представления будет чем-то вроде `7.9999999999999991118....`

Примерно так можно округлить с регулируемой точностью:

```
function ceilWithPrecision($value, $precision=1e-10){
  if(abs($value - (int)$value) > $precision){
    return ceil($value);
  }
  return (int)$value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Это действительно косяк чисел с плавающей запятой, проверял [тут](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/).

```
<?php
$a = 123+3.5;
$b = 1.15;
$ab = $a/$b;
echo $a . ' / ' . $b . ' = ' . $ab . PHP_EOL;
echo ($a-126.5) . ' / ' . ($b-1.15) . ' = ' . ($ab-110) . PHP_EOL;
var_dump($a, $b, $ab)
?>
```

Вот с таким кодом выдает:

```
126.5 / 1.15 = 110
0 / 0 = 1.4210854715202E-14
float(126.5)
float(1.15)
float(110)
```

Хочу отметить, что потери точности у **$a** и **$b** нет, а потеря происходит при делении.

Не знал, что **echo** и **var_dump** могут форматировать вывод сами.